# Inequality of a p-laplacian

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Let $\Omega$ be a bounded domain with lipschitzian boundary.$2\leq p$
Why do we have $$\int_{\Omega}\langle|\nabla u|^{p-2}\nabla u- |\nabla v |^{p-2}\nabla v,\nabla v\rangle\leq \int_{\Omega}(|\nabla u|^{p-2}+ |\nabla v |^{p-2})|\nabla u-\nabla v||\nabla v|$$ for all $u,v\in W^{1,p}(\Omega)$?

Comment: You forgot about some differentials. What is $u$? What is $v$? Add some details so your question doesn't look so bad. Imagine someone comes here and sees how bad it was written, it has no details at all. Do you think such person would be willing to help you

Comment: The left hand side integral does not make sense. You write a scalar product, but the first factor is not a vector.